# I need to optimize an upsert plpgsql function for dynamic random columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

| sno | mp_tags | mp_class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | last four | last three |
| 2 | Null | last two |
| 3 | Null | null |

as per the data table picture shown, I have created a table in postgresql database with 3 columns:

```
sno smallserial, -- sno == serial no
mp_tags varchar(50),
mp_class varchar(100)
```

also as per the picture under the `mp_tags` column there is one data `"last four"` and under the `mp_class` column there are two data `"last three"`, `"last two"`.
in the column `mp_tags` row 2 & 3 are null and in column `mp_class` row 3 is null.

if there is any new data I want to insert under any column (`mp_tags` or `mp_class`), I am looking to update the null value of the column if there are any null value.

now, under `mp_tags` column I want to insert a new data `"last ten"`.
as under `mp_tags` column at row 2 there is no value, so I want the new `"last ten"` value to be updated there. and also I dont want any data to be duplicate.

based on the above requirement this is the code that I have written.

looking for suggestions and advice on how better I could have written this code without using loops and at the same time with using internal PostgreSQL framework functions. I am right now using PostgreSQL version 15.

here is my function :

```
create or replace function initials_upsert(upsert jsonb) returns varchar as $$
    declare
        key text; value text;
        is_null boolean;
        line int;
    begin
        foreach key in array array(select jsonb_object_keys(upsert)) loop
        foreach value in array array(select jsonb_array_elements_text(upsert->key)) loop
        execute format('select 1 from initials where %I is null', key) into is_null;
            if is_null then execute format('select sno from initials where %I is null order by %I asc', key,key) into line;
                execute format('update initials set %I = %L where %I is null and not exists(select 1 from initials where lower(%I)=lower(%L))', key,value,key,key,value);
            else execute format('insert into initials (%I) select %L where not exists (select 1 from initials where lower(%I)=lower(%L))', key,value,key,value);
            end if; end loop; end loop;
        return 'dude looks like a lady';
    end; $$ language plpgsql;

explain analyse select initials_upsert('{"mp_tags":["last four","tom"]}'::jsonb);
```

I need to minimize loop and run-time also space complexity .